# SVN client with both Windows shell extension and Eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, visualsvn

I'm extensively using TortoiseSVN because of its seamless integration in Windows and also for its client-side hooking capabilities.
I now want to manage my interaction with the SVN repository through Eclipse.
I know about Subclipse and Subversive but neither of them seem to have this client-side hook functionality nor any kind of interaction with TortoiseSVN (which is already installed and set up).

I know for a fact that VisualSVN has the client-side hook functionality and also a plug-in for Visual Studio, which makes it easier and more intuitive to work with SVN (from the file system and the IDE).

Ultimately, I'm looking for a client like VisualSVN, i.e. that will integrate seamlessly with both Windows Explorer and Eclipse.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, TortoiseSVN is the only Subversion client which is implemented as Windows Shell extension. There is no such Subversion client that integrates both with Eclipse and Windows Shell. BTW, Eclipse is a cross-platform IDE, so I doubt that such plug-in could actually exist.

---

*Please note that such questions are offtopic on StackOverflow:*

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.